# Xfce. Show last notifications keyborard shortcut

Tags: xfce, xfce-panel

On xfce there's the bell on the panel that I click to view last notifications. I'd like to popup the last notifications window with a keyboard shortcut. How is it possible to do this?

OS - Xubuntu 20.04. xfce4 v.4.14

Comment: @guiverc are you able to answer this question now that the OP has provided OS and Xfce version details?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is *exactly* what you want, but on my installed of Ubuntu Studio 20.04 with Xfce 4.14, `ctrl+backtick` seems to undo the dismissal of the last notification, so if you keep pressing it you can see all of the previous notifications. I discovered this because I wanted to use the `ctrl+backtick` shortcut to toggle the visibility of [Guake Terminal](http://guake-project.org/), but found it was already in use, and I want to stop it showing the last notification so I can use it for Guake!

So how to *remove* the shortcut is another question, though it sounds like @guiverc might have an idea?